# how to store recently visited pages/routes in sails?

Tags: sails.js

Need to store the list of recently visited pages inside the app, something like recently opened files list in the windows. What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on many things, particularly if your app has a user-based system or not.

If your app has a notion of user accounts:

For your `User` model, add an extra attribute `recentPages: {type: 'ARRAY', defaultsTo: [] }`. Wherever you handle the user's login session, you should set `req.session.user` to the instance of the current user.

Then create a global policy **trackUsers.js** in your `/api/policies` folder:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    req.session.user.recentPages.append(req.url);
    req.session.user.save(function (err) {
      return next();
    });
  } else {
    return next();
  }
};
```

When you want to access a user's recent pages, just grab it from `user.recentPages`. You can limit the number of pages added by doing a quick check in your policy and deleting elements; there's also a validation from [Waterline ORM](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#validations) for models called **maxLength**.

---

If your app doesn't, then you can possibly track by IP address instead. This is riskier but the only workaround I can think of (risky due to shared IPs, dynamic IPs would render this feature inaccurate).

You would create a new model called `User` in `/api/models` that has an attribute `ipAddress: { type: 'STRING', ip: true, primary: true }` and another attribute `recentPages: {type: 'ARRAY', defaultsTo: [] }`.

Then create a global policy **trackUsers.js** in your `/api/policies` folder.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  User.find(req.ip, function foundUser (err, user) {
    if (!err && user) {
      user.recentPages.append(req.url);
      user.save(function (err) {
        return next();
      });
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  });
};
```

You can access an IP address's recent pages by doing a lookup on the `User` model with the IP that you grab on the client side. Make sure that regardless of which method you use, you add the policy to `config/policies.js`: `'*': ['trackUsers']`